# ARM GCC inline assembly error on %w operand

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, linaro

I have an ARMv8 inline assembly segment:

```
/* get leading 0 of cache ways */
__asm__ __volatile__
(
  "CLZ %w[shift], %w[maxWay] \n"
  : [shift] "=r" (uiShift)
  : [maxWay] "r" (uiMaxWay)
);
```

When compile by ARM GCC compiler:

[image]

Interestingly, if I compile with Linaro compiler, then there is no problem.

[image]

Is there a problem in ARM GCC compiler, or in my code?

Comment: Use the `__builtin_clz` instead of assembly. Anyway, what are your operand types and why do you need `w`. PS: don't post code as images.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike x86 where the same compiler can produce x86-32 or x86-64 code with `-m32` and `-m64`, you need a separate build of gcc for ARM vs. AArch64.

ARM gcc accepts `-march=armv8-a`, but it's still compiling in 32-bit ARM mode, not AArch64.

I can reproduce your problem [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'unsigned+int+clz_builtin(unsigned+uiShift)+%7B%0A++++return+__builtin_clz(uiShift)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%23if+1%0Aunsigned+int+clz(unsigned+uiMaxWay)+%7B%0A++++unsigned+uiShift%3B%0A++++__asm__+__volatile__%0A++++(%0A++++%22CLZ+%25w%5Bshift%5D,+%25w%5BmaxWay%5D+%5Cn%22%0A++++:+%5Bshift%5D+%22%3Dr%22+(uiShift)%0A++++:+%5BmaxWay%5D+%22r%22+(uiMaxWay)%0A++++)%3B%0A++++return+uiShift%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%23endif%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.64982414073119,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armg630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-march%3Darmv8-a+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.386214921125514,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+ARM+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:33.386214921125514,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g630,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-march%3Darmv8-a+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'ARM64+gcc+6.3.0+(linux)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.96396093814331,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with AArch64 gcc and ARM gcc.  (And I included an example that uses `__builtin_clz(uiShift)` instead of inline asm, so it compiles to a `clz` instruction on either architecture.)

BTW, you could have left out the `w` size override on both operands, and simply use `unsigned int` for the input and output.  Then the same inline asm would work with both ARM and AArch64.  (But `__builtin_clz` is still better, because the compiler understands what it does.  e.g. it knows the result is in the range 0..31, which may enable some optimizations.)

Comment: Thanks. I just remove 'w' then.

Comment: @RayXu: why not `__builtin_clz`?  It will compile at least as efficiently as your inline asm.